# How do you debug (trace execution) of a pylons web application?

Tags: python, debugging, pylons, trace

How do you debug (trace execution) of a pylons web application?

(using a mac with textmate)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[It's really easy](http://pylonsbook.com/en/1.1/logging.html)

To sum it up, import the [python logging module](http://docs.python.org/library/logging.html) and send debug messages to the terminal on your Mac where you have the paste server running.

```
import logging
log = logging.getLogger(__name__)
log.debug('Your trace message')
```

This will show up in whatever terminal your paste server is running in as:

> **17:14:51,060 DEBUG [your_app.controllers.your_controller] Your trace message**